# Do not apply requestFocus on EditText that is inside CarouselView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, setfocus

I have a `EditText` in the `RecyclerView` item that, once the item is selected, I want to display the keyboard and Focus on the `EditText`, but I do not do anything.

**I use the CarouselView library, which is the same as the RecyclerView.**

**In Activity:**

```
listStudent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CarouselView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(CarouselView carouselView, int position, int adapterPosition, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {

                try {
                      View view = listStudent.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(listStudent.getCurrentAdapterPosition());
                      final EditText ed = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.edScore);
                      ed.requestFocus();

                      ed.post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                              InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                              AppController.Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                              imm.showSoftInput(ed, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                      }});

                 } catch (Exception ex) {}
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemDeselected(CarouselView carouselView, int position, int adapterPosition, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {

            }
     });
```

**In XML Item Child**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@xml/layout_border_color_primary"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="5"
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add inside your try block

```
ed.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but if you look, this code is written in xml. Is not enough? But I added the same code but did not work.

Comment: imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0); add this

Comment: did not work. Do you think there is a different way, or even there is another library that can be used the same way?